# String segmentation loop

Tags: foreach

I want to loop `\score`，but it prompt error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\goforeach #1->\foreach 
                        \num in {#1} { the value is \num } 
l.28 ...ndafter\goforeach\expandafter\myfunc\textA
```

Who can help me, ths, my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{`}
\DTLloaddb{tabscores}{reportData.csv}
\DTLgetvalue{\score}{tabscores}{1}{2}%score value is 6,1,7.3,2,3.3


\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{O{,} >{\SplitList{,}}m}{
    \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Define list separator with one delay
    \ProcessList{#2}{\myitem}}

\newcommand\myitem[1]{\itemdelim${#1}$}

\newcommand{\goforeach}[1]{%
    \foreach \num in {#1}
    {
        the value is \num
    }
}

\begin{document}
\def\textA{\score}
\myfunc{\score}
\expandafter\goforeach\expandafter\myfunc\textA
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ideally you should make your minimal example *complete* as well. To that end, you should include what `reportData.csv` looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some guesswork, I can offer you a macro that should do what you need.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
x`list
A`6,1,7.3,2,3.3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{`}
\DTLloaddb{tabscores}{\jobname.csv}
\DTLgetvalue{\score}{tabscores}{1}{2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{O{,}mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {#1} #2
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq #3
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\myitem[1]{\item $#1$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\myfunc\score\myitem
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much that this is the answer I want, just latex3 grammar I'm not proficient

Answer (score 1):

To use the `\foreach \num in {..}` syntax, you need [`pgffor`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgffor):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\score{6,1,7.3,2,3.3}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{O{,} >{\SplitList{,}}m}{
    \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Define list separator with one delay
    \ProcessList{#2}{\myitem}}

\newcommand\myitem[1]{\itemdelim${#1}$}

\newcommand{\goforeach}[1]{%
    \foreach \num in {#1}
    {%
        the value is \num\par
    }
}

\begin{document}

\myfunc{\score}

\expandafter\goforeach\expandafter{\score}

\end{document}
```

Note how I've changed the format of your call to `\goforeach`, which shouldn't use the output of `\myfunc`.